# Estimator $\gamma = \sum a_i\times x_i$ , where $X_i \sim \exp(t_i \theta )$ Show $\gamma$ is unbiased if $\sum a_i/t_i = 1$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution, estimators

I'm getting really confused with the estimators in this question!

$X_i \sim \exp(t_i \theta x)$ where $t_i$ are positive constants.

The MLE for $\theta = \frac n{\sum t_i x_i}$

And $\phi = 1/\theta$ so MLE is $ \frac {\sum t_i x_i}n $ by invariance property

New estimator $ \gamma = \sum a_i x_i $ where $a_i$ are real numbers

How do I prove that for $\gamma$ to be unbiased for $\phi$, $ \sum a_i/t_i  = 1 $ ?

And hence ${\rm var}(\gamma) = \phi^2 \sum (a_i/t_i)^2 $ ?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! If this is a homework question, could you please add the self-study tag? Thanks

Comment: If you apply the definition of unbiased estimator to $\gamma$, the answer should drop right out.  Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to figure out the condition for $\gamma$ to be unbiased for $\phi$ by directly applying the definition of unbiasedness and given you know the expectation of $X_i$. The variance calculation can be done since you can also get the variance of $X_i$.